# :first-child not returning any elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I must be missing some nuance on the `:first-child` pseudo-selector. I have the following in my code (where `je` is a jQuery object corresponding to a node in the DOM):

```
const errors = je.find('div.error');
console.log(errors.length + ' errors found');
const firstError = je.find('div.error:first-child');
console.log(firstError.length + ' first errors found ');
```

The above logs:

```
1 errors found
0 first errors found
```

If some elements *were* found, shouldn't I expect the `:first-child` pseudo-selector to return the first of them?

jFiddle SSCCE [here](https://jsfiddle.net/7vany8nb/)

Comment: you already have the error divs found, just save the first one using https://api.jquery.com/first/

Comment: @Huangism you're right - I read the code wrong. OP, your code works in the right scenario: https://jsfiddle.net/pkx418or/. We need to see your HTML structure in order to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If some elements were found, shouldn't I expect the `:first-child` pseudo-selector to return the first of them?

Why would you? If you have a set of elements that may or may not be related by parent, how would `:first-child` among those elements be meaningful? Even if they did all have the same parent, `:first-child` would still only match an element if it really is the first child of its parent, as the name implies. If *all* of the elements in the set are the first child of their respective parents, then `:first-child` would match *all* of them.

The first element in a set of matches is represented by `:first`, not `:first-child`.